# How to make uwsgi --http-to be able to handle multiple responses at the same time?

Tags: http, proxy, uwsgi

I have a uWSGI 2.0.12 uwsgi server running:

```
$ cat myt.py
import uwsgi
def application(env, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
  for i in xrange(100):
    yield 'Hello, World %i<br>\n' % i
    uwsgi.async_sleep(1)
$ uwsgi --uwsgi-socket 127.0.0.1:5423 --async 99 --ugreen --module myt
```

So each response takes about 100 seconds to generate, 1 line of it takes 1 second.

If I change --uwsgi-socket to --http-socket, then it works just fine when I visit http://127.0.0.1:5423/ in 2 Chrome tabs: in each second, a new line appears in each tab.

However, I want to keep --uwsgi-socket, and I want to add a proxy which will convert from HTTP to uwsgi. I decided to use `uwsgi --http-to` as this proxy, and I've started 2 proxies:

```
$ uwsgi --uwsgi-socket 127.0.0.1:5423 --async 99 --ugreen --module myt
$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:4114 --http-to '127.0.0.1:5423' --master
$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:5115 --http-to '127.0.0.1:5423' --master
```

When I visit http://127.0.0.1:4114/, it works fine: it starts displaying lines in each second. However, when I visit the same link in a new tab, nothing happens for 100 seconds (until the previous requests finishes), and lines start appear only then. So either the proxy or the uwsgi server on port 5423 aren't able to handle multiple requests at the same time. To confirm that it's the proxy who is unable, I visit http://127.0.0.1:4114/ and at the same time in another tab, I visit http://127.0.0.1:5115/ , and the lines start appearing in both tabs. So 1 proxy can handle 1 response at a time.

This doesn't work in parallel either:

```
$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:5544 --master --http-workers 9 --http-events 99 --route='^/.* uwsgi:127.0.0.1:5423,0,0' --workers 9
```

**My question:** How can I configure `uwsgi --http-to` so that it can handle at least 100 responses at a time?

I've tried specifying `--threads 100`, `--processes 100`, `--async 100 --ugreen`, `--http-workers 9`, `--http-events 99` or specifying the `--http-to` flags multiple times in the same command-line, but none of these helped.

Right now I'm not interested in alternative proxy software such as NGINX or making my `uwsgi --uwsgi-socket` instance understand the HTTP protocol directly. I need additional command-line flags for `uwsgi --http-to` to make it able to handle multiple responses at the same time.

Comment: Where you able to parallelize using  `uwsgi-socket`

Answer (score 1):

All of settings for http server are prefixed with `http`. List of all options is [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#plugin-http)

What you need is `http-workers` option, to tell uWSGI to spawn multiple workers for HTTP request processing

Comment: Specifying `--http-workers 9` indeed started more workers (9 instead of 1), but it didn't make any difference. The problem still persists.

Comment: I have extended the question so that the failure is easier to reproduce. If you think that `http-workers` should solve it, you can easily try now if it indeed solves it on your machine.

Comment: Latest update. It works fine even with a single HTTP worker (i.e. no `--http-workers ...`) from Firefox 44, but no parallel connections from Chrome 48. It's unrelated to proxy mode, it seems Chrome is not sending the 2nd request even when connecting to a `--http-socket` Python app directly.